# I m trying to send pdf attachment in gmail and webmail. In gmail it works properly but when it goes to webmail pdf file showing corrupt and 0 byte

Tags: php

I m trying to send pdf attachment in gmail and webmail. In gmail it works properly but when it goes to webmail pdf file showing corrupt and 0 byte.it goes in gmail,yahoomail,and other mail is ok but in webmail it's not working file is going to webmail but when i m trying to open that pdf it showing file corrupt. Please help me out anyone.code bellow:-

```
$info_send_mail = $obj->select(TABLEPRIFIX.'send_mail','link',['sale_id'=>$info[0]['sale_id']]);// Fetch data
    $filename = $info_send_mail[0]['link']; // fetch file name
    $path = 'http://webfreakers.com/crm/admin/pdf/sendmail'; 
    $file = $path . "/" . $filename;
    $mailto = $info[0]['email'];
    $subject = 'Invoice';
    $message = 'Check your invoice';

    // retrive file from the folder
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    // a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";

    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: Universal Survey & Analysis Services <sms@webfreakers.com>" . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;

    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    //SEND Mail
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>Mail sent successfully</p>';
        header('location:../sales_list.php');
    } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        print_r( error_get_last() );
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>Mail not sent</p>';
        header('location:../sales_list.php');
}
```

Comment: Were you able to get a fix for this ? It is the other way for me, pdf goes fine to webmail, but when sending to gmail it says file corrupt.

Comment: I did a quick check & realized, it is a problem with the mail client. On opening the gmail from a chrome browser through mail.google.com instead of the Apple Mail client, it was opening the file perfectly! Strange.